# How to check how many elements of a certain type has a page with Chrome Extension Dev

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple custom Chrome Extension I've looked all over the web for this and nothing good showed up. I want to read how many elements of a certain type are in a page, through my `popup.js` file.

Something like this:

```
$('div').length
```

Is it possible to do this through the `chrome.tabs` command?

Comment: Define "do this through `executeScript`". You want `executeScript` to return a value?

Comment: @Xan I am using it with the `chrome.tabs` command to stuff via javascript to the `activeTab`, what I need now is to retrieve information, like `$('div').length` from the activeTab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `manifest.json`:

   ```js
   "permissions": [
       "tabs",
       "activeTab"
   ]
   ```
2. Code:

   ```js
   function countTags(tag, callback) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript({
           code: "document.getElementsByTagName('" + tag + "').length"
       }, function(result) {
           if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
               console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
           } else {
               callback(result[0]);
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Usage:

   ```js
   countTags("div", function(num) {
       console.log("Found %i divs", num);
   });
   ```

   `getElementsByTagName(tag)` can be replaced with `querySelectorAll(selector)` or jQuery syntax if you are sure the tab has jQuery loaded.

Comment: Thank you :) Can you please explain whats going on in the function?

Comment: Chrome tabs API uses function callbacks for almost everything so `chrome.tabs.query` passes the active tab to the first callback function, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` injects js in this tab that finds all specified tags and returns the number, which is available in the second callback function as `result[0]`, then the original `callback` function is called with this number.

Comment: `result` is an array? Why does it contain a `[0]`?

Comment: Yes, it's an array, make use of the API [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: Thanks to your answer I got to finally understand how this works, thanks you very much :)