# Chrome extension - get img src if image is wrapped inside link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, contextmenu

I just coded a little script which allows me to upload images directly to my server via a simple contextMenu Item.
The whole thing looks (simplified to its core) basicly something like that:

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    var newURL = "http://xxxxxxxx.xx/gallery/";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "XXX",
    "contexts": ["image", "link"],
    "onclick" : function(e) {
        var url = e.srcUrl,
        x = url.split('/');

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://xxxxxxxx.xx/xxx.php?url='+encodeURI(url)+'&auth=xxx&name='+x.pop(), true);
        xhr.send();
    }
});
```

Everything else is getting handled by my server on the other side.

The problem is that I don't know how to get to a img SRC if the whole think is wrapped in a link context.

If it's just an image the url is easily obtainable by using **e.srcUrl**.

But if I click on a link there's just **e.linkUrl** and, as far as I know, no reference to the actual image inside of it.

Is there an easy easy way to get the img src if context==link?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you even have the `"link"` context there, then?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` (requires `tabs` and `activeTab` permission in manifest.json) to inject `document.activeElement.querySelector('img').src` code and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30380827/3959875) the value.