# Get div text content from content page to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get the text content of a `<div>` from the content page from within a chrome extension?

The scenario is:

From a certain webpage **www.****.com/page.html**, it has a code of:

```
<div id="pageDiv">
TEXT FROM DIV
</div>
```

When a user opens the chrome extension from the chrome bar (opens *popup.html*), it must get the value of the `pageDiv` from the content page and insert the text to the chrome extension's *popup.html*.

Comment: The short answer to this is "Yes". If you want an implementation of something similar, you can see [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39319198/3773011).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the whole text contained in webpage using Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317541/extract-the-whole-text-contained-in-webpage-using-chrome-extension)